# Alerts when approaching daily quota on Google mapping API (geocoding, places, directions, etc.)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3, alert, google-geocoding-api, gcp-alerts

How can I get alerted when we reach a certain percentage of the daily mapping API usage quotas?

We want to set up alerts that warn us when we reach 85% of the daily quotas that we set up for Google API usage (i.e. geocoding, places, and directions APIs).

One source mentioned that this can be done using the Google Cloud Platform's alerting functionality, but I don't see the mapping APIs listed there in the list of alerting options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to set up alerts when Google mapping API usage daily quota reaches 85%.

This can be done using the Google Cloud Platform's alerting functionality, in order to create a alerting policy on Google mapping API follow the steps mentioned in the link [1].

[1] https://support.woolpert.io/hc/en-us/articles/360045341333-How-to-set-and-use-service-level-alerts-on-Google-Maps-Platform

For more information you can refer this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits).